# A more appropriate sentence for “I hope you are the right person to ask.”

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

I feel “I hope you are the right person.” doesn’t sound suitable for emailing professors. To me, it sounds a little rude, or cheesy, I don’t know...

Any suggestions for alternatives???

Comment: Technical question, or confused undergrad wondering if "Chinese Poetry in Translation" will count as credit towards the breadth requirement? Context matters here, as does your relationship to the Prof.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I actually know nothing about these profs. I am emailing them to gather more information about admission requirements as an international student.

Comment: Sorry, it's been 40 years since I last had to write that sort of correspondence. I'm sure though, that there's someone around here who's done it within the past decade.

Comment: "I hope you can answer some questions for me" ?

Comment: "I have heard about your knowledge of ***[psolimestry]*** so I would be grateful if you could find the time to advise me about some aspects, such as . . ."

Comment: I agree that the notion of "hoping" used w/"[having found] the right person" might seem a bit "forward" & I'd omit "right" in sentence 1 (but it's ok in the 2d one, imo: ..."I am writing you to see if you are the person who I should be contacting to find out [more] about admission requirements for international students [at school X]. If I have reached the right person, I would be very grateful if you would answer the following questions. If, however, I’ve contacted you in error, I’d be equally grateful if you would accept my apology & direct me & my questions to the right office: [Q1/etc]."

Comment: @PapaPoule "I would be very grateful if you would answer the following questions" is a thinly disguised interrogation. Perhaps "I would be very grateful if you could advise me about the following matters."

Comment: @WeatherVane I Googled 'psolimestry' and for just about the first time ever got 'no result'. Google suggests I might want solomostry or palmistry.

Comment: @NigelJ oh that was for the example! We don't know what the area of expertise is.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I know but I was curious. What is it ?

Comment: @NigelJ I made it up for the example, and like you, I checked if it is a word ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane Yours below is certainly a great answer (+1) to the nonspecific question as asked (which is the only question that matters). My suggestion above was trying to take into account OP's comment, which led me to believe that s/he was trying to locate the person officially responsible for (& not just someone knowledgeable enough to) answer/ing questions re admission requirements. In that case (where it's one of the Prof's jobs to answer such questions), perhaps coming across as an interrogation would be less out of place (although I would change "would" to "**c**ould answer").

Answer (score 3):

> Dear Professor Zoom,
>
> I am studying psolimestry, and my research has revealed that you are
>   an expert in this field.
>
> I would be very grateful if you could find the time to resolve some of my
>   doubts.
>
> The first matter I find difficult to understand is . . .
>
> I am also struggling with a contradiction between . . .
>
> I do hope you can advise me.
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> Weather Vane

Comment: +1 Quoth Google: "Did you mean palmistry, psalmistry, solomostry, psalmistre"    My only reservation with your answer is that it would be better if you warned the student not to ask a question that could be easily answered by some intensive Googling.

Comment: @ab2 the question was how to ask an esteemed professor without seeming to be rude. Not how to research my fake topic, which you fell for along with NigelJ. My topic was **not** easily answered with google.

Comment: I didn't "fall for it", I just Googled it because I Google almost everything.

Answer (score 2):

I think personal choice is going to be the deciding factor here. I would say, "I assume I am addressing this question to the right person(s)."

Comment: The important thing though is the unknown professor's personal preference for how things should be worded in an email like this. Getting *that* right increases probability of helpful response.